# received data from react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have trouble with received data.

I create actions with axios and know this is working well, Have promise with status 200 and GET.

Then i want initial function HandleClick on button onClick, on my container fetch_users, so i create new container :

```
class FetchUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('thisporps', this.props)
    this.props.fetchUsers()
    console.log('this.props.fetchUSers')
  }

render() {
return (
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>FetchUsers</button>
  )
}
}
o
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchUsers }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FetchUsers);
```

and onClick I want run function handleClick.

Next step on my user-list container i want received that data from request

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class UserList extends Component {
  renderList(userData) {
    console.log('userData', userData)
    return (
      <div>Bleh</div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>user ID: </th>
            <th>Week Nr: </th>
            <th>Days number: </th>
            <th>User email: </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ users }) {
  return {
    users: users
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

and i have no idea why on this console.log(userData) doesn't work and doesn't received any data.

Comment: Declare your props in your component !

Comment: Where did you call renderList function ? I think you are using redux the wrong way. Redux is for sharing state between component. It's seems like you should use listeners.

Comment: I paste the codepen link. I use redux like this way :
user click onClick button -> action creator return type: USERS_LIST -> action creator return an action , then go pass to middleware, logs it -> going to reducer, and reducer process the action and return the new state.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWRPGz

Comment: I don't see where you call renderList function.

Comment: Ok, right. I didn't call it. Thanks bro, I overlooking it...